# Oracle Forms 10g Sticky Cursor

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I face a really strange problem. The problem is that sometimes the cursor does not listen to mouse, it become suck on the field and does not move to any other field when using mouse navigation but navigation works as expected when using the tab key.

Has anybody else faced the "Sticky Cursor" problem? Oracle support says, that problem is fixed by installing newest Java update, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the problem you are facing. The last Oracle Forms application I worked on 2 - 3 years ago was plagued by the same issue.

I spent a long time working with Oracle Support investigating the issue but even after applying successive Oracle Form patches, later versions of the Java Runtime Environment and code changes to the Forms the problem remained.

In case it is of use here is a link to [question](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1061098) I raised on the Oracle Forms OTN Forum asking if the problem remained on Oracle Forms 11g.

Unfortunately I was never able to resolve the problem. I hope you have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different causes for this to happen.

1) You use timers in your application. Just avoid using timers if possible this is a main cause of having problems with the mouse focus.

2) Some versions of java or jinitiator have also problems with the mouse focus. So try to use the latest versions of java 6 (version 24 or above or something like that), you can also use java 7 of course.

3) There are also a few patches of the application server to fix mouse focus problems. You have to check them all. If the right ones are installed this should fix all your problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the "Sticky Cursor" and I tried (just for testing) the following:

- If the form has Required Fields, just change the Required property from YES to NO.
- If the form has Radio Buttons no visibles, make it visibles.

Try this only to testing purpose and tell me if works because I do that and in some cases works for my apps.